# pdf download link, but file may be stored in a non-public folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, asp.net-mvc-4

In my production environment, when a pdf file is uploaded, it will be probably uploaded to a folder that is not publicly accessible (admins force this on us).

So I need to provide a link where visitors to the website can download a pdf file that they uploaded previously, how can I do this if the folder isn't publicly accessible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an MVC action and add `return File(some path)`.
This will read the file and send it down the HTTP response.

Make sure that attackers cannot use your action to read `..\..\My Documents\Intersting Stuff`.

Comment: I don't have that folder "Interesting Stuff", should I be worried? :)

Comment: @user1361315: Certainly.  Either use a whitelist, or use very strict validation of the name.  Better yet, use ID numbers only.

Comment: the action just takes a guid that represents an object in the database, and that db record has the name of the file.

Comment: @user1361315: Yes; that's the best approach.